# Perl, Mojolicious, Helper, call method

Tags: helper, mojolicious

I see in *Mojolicious::Plugin::Yancy* helper declaration:

`$app->helper( 'yancy.get' => \&_helper_get );`

and after that they call helper like

`$c->yancy->get( $schema, $id );`

But when i try

`$app->helper( 'foo.bar' => \&foo_bar_func );`

and

`$c->foo->bar();`

i have error: *can't call method "bar" without a package or object referace*.

When i try:

`$app->helper( 'foobar' => \&foo_bar_func );`

and

`$c->foo_bar();`

...all is ok.

But how does it work in Yancy with "->" ?

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Adding-a-plugin-to-your-application

Helpers with a dot in them belong to a particular plugin. Are you registering yours within plugin 'foo'?